# Error:org.gradle.tooling.model.GradleProject.getBuildDirectory()Ljava/io/File;

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, intellij-13

After upgrading to **IntelliJ  IDEA 13.1.5** I can't build android project. The error looks like this::

> Gradle 'myProject' project refresh failed
>   Error:org.gradle.tooling.model.GradleProject.getBuildDirectory()Ljava/io/File;

How it can be solved?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of the Android Gradle plugin are you using?

Comment: @ScottBarta, Gradle 1.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved by update from http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+13.1+EAP instead of the patch update.

JetBrains Support Request: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/requests/39301